# Как повысить API у apk?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

Для создания `.apk` использую `python kivy` и `buildozer`. Пытаюсь загрузить `аpk-файл` в `google play`. Гугл выдает следующую ошибку:

"Сбой при загрузке.
Целевой уровень API для вашего приложения – 27. Чтобы обеспечить необходимую производительность и безопасность, целевой уровень API должен быть не ниже 28. Установите для своего приложения целевой уровень API не менее 28."

Мои действия:
В `buildozer.spec` изменил строку `#android.api = 27`
на строку: `android.api = 28`
(оставил строку раскомментированной)
Сохранил изменения.

После чего, при сборке apk-файла `buildozer` выдаёт ошибку:

```
# Command failed: 

/home/vladimir/.buildozer/android/platform/android-

sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools

# ENVIRONMENT:

#     LS_COLORS = 

'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:

cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=

34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;

31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz

=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=

01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=0

1;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tb

z2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*

.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;3

1:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01

;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.m

jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;3

5:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=

01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.

mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;

35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=

01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.a

vi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.

xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35

:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=0

0;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav

=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'

#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'

#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'

#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'

#     DISPLAY = ':0'

#     OLDPWD = '/home/vladimir/.buildozer/android/platform/android-

sdk/platform-tools/api'

#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'

#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'

#     USERNAME = 'vladimir'

#     XDG_VTNR = '2'

#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'

#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'

#     USER = 'vladimir'

#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'

#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = 

'/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/04eceb86_46ea_4bb8_8044_00eb6026f006'

#     PWD = '/home/vladimir/Desktop/dist/calc3'

#     HOME = '/home/vladimir'

#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1615'

#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'

#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'

#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = 

'/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/deskt

op'

#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'

#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'

#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'

#     WINDOWPATH = '2'

#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'

#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'

#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'

#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'

#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'

#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'

#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'

#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.69'

#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'

#     SHLVL = '1'

#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'

#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'

#     LOGNAME = 'vladimir'

#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'

#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'

#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'

#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'

#     PATH = '/home/vladimir/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-

1.9.4/bin:/home/vladimir/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/u

sr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/ho

me/vladimir/.local/bin/'

#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'

#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-

unix/1291,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1291'

#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'

#     _ = '/home/vladimir/.local/bin/buildozer'

# 

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command

# The error might be hidden in the log above this error

# Please read the full log, and search for it before

# raising an issue with buildozer itself.

# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Подскажите, каким образом возможно увеличить API у apk-файла до 28?

P.S. Также я изменил в `buildozer.spec` строку `package.name = myapp` на строку `package.name = СalcXv1`, но думаю к ошибке выше - это вряд ли имеет отношение.

Comment: Забавно. Я все верно понял, что, гугл запрещает загружать в Гугл плэй приложения, которые созданы с поддержкой старых версий Android?

Comment: Да, API у  .apk должен быть не ниже минимальных требований от гугл. На текущий момент API должен быть не ниже 28.

Comment: @Александр не надо путать целевое API (targetSDKVersion) и минимальное API (minSDKversion). У гугла претензии именно к первому параметру, который на поддержку старых версий никак не влияет.

Comment: SDK для api 28 вы себе поставили уже?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Да, это помогло. По поводу ошибки выше: причина была в конфликте openjdk 8 и 11 версий.